# react-native missing files on libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using

- react-native : 0.59
- M1 Monterey
- XCode 13.3
- nvm node 10

I got these errors

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '***/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTBlob.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '***/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '***/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a'
```

and so on.

What I already did

- pod deintegrate and pod update
- reinstalling packages and relinking
- reinstalling cocoapods
- resintalling homebrew
- resintalling XCode 13
- Delete DerivedData and Pods
- Reinstalling using arch -x86_64
- Recreating Podfile
- Changed deployment target to ios11
- Clean and Build

What else should I try?
Thank you